# When do I have to free memory?

Tags: c++, memory

I learned C# and now I'm learning C++. The whole point of releasing a memory is new for me, and I want to know when I need to worry about memory releasing and when I don't.

From what I understand, the only case I have to worry about the release of memory, is when I used `new` operator, so I should to release the memory by using `delete`.
But in these cases there is no need to release the memory:

- Class variables (Members), or static variables.
- Local variables in function.
- STL family (string, list, vector, etc.).

Is this true?
And are there other cases where I have to worry about memory releasing?

Comment: A related, but tangential topic, is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: Of utmost importance are the concepts of **ownership** and **object lifetimes** (on top of RAII).  Especially with the availability of pointers (plain and smart) and references, your code should make it crystal-clear what objects owns what data.  This is especially important if you ever use threads with your program.  Also, use valgrind judiciously in your testing to verify memory cleanliness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You basically got it right: You need to balance `new` with `delete`, `new[]` with `delete[]`, and `malloc` with `free`.

Well-written C++ will contain almost none of those, since you leave the responsibiltiy for dynamic memo­ry and lifetime management to suitable container or manager classes, most notably `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Note how there are crazy cases where due to a typedef you use `new` but have to use `delete[]`

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Hm, well, more accurately, the craziness comes from the fact that the "`[]`" in `new[]` isn't lexically near the word "`new`", and sometimes it can be on a completely different line :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb I tend to abide by the following:

- If I code a `new/new[]` i immediately code the corresponding `delete/delete[]`
- Likewise any `malloc/calloc` is immediately followed by the relevant `free`

This avoids many nasty situations where you can generate a memory leak.
If you are new to C++ I would not get used to `malloc` and its many variants, it requires a lot of scaffolding to remain type-safe, which unless truly necessary can be counted as a **bad** thing, however, as mentioned, there are times it is necessary: for example, when having to use C-based libraries/APIs then you may conceivably need to use them.

In the main stay well clear of them and your life will be much easier.

**Note:** I mention the points above, as having gone from C to C++ I have had to face up to a lot of old tried and tested techniques from C which cause problems in C++.

Comment: In the face of early `return`, `break` or exceptions, you migth need a bit more thinking than just putting a `delete|delete[]|free` blindly after the `new|new[]|malloc`. Even if you use them, you can use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` to manage the memory in a safe way.

Comment: I agree entirely, I did not mean to imply these were catch-all fixes:) I merely meant that when coding each `new|new[]|malloc|calloc`  the relevant `delete|delete[]|free` type should be placed at the correct part of the code (not blindly:).  In regards of early `return` and `break` I code with the principle of only having one single exit point from a function, so I rarely encounter that as a problem, however, yes you're right: in regards of early termination from a function you would need to plan for that and delete appropriately/ rethink the flow of the function & have a single return point.

Comment: And if you really do manual cleanup, you should wrap the allocation inside a `try-catch` block, after all, a function you are calling might `throw`. Sadly C++ doesn't have a `try-finally`...

Comment: Cheers:)  I ran out of characters in the last comment and was penning an addendum, you beat me to it:)